# Page VS Sub-Domains - Not sure which way to go

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a site for a friend. She is a Author / Freelancer. I want to have her site split up between an "Author" and a "Freelancer" Section. Maybe 2 buttons on the main page where people can choose which direction they need to go.

I'm in a fix if I should create a new page or a sub domain for each area?

Are there any things I need to consider in this regard? Any pro's con's?

Thans guys :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which features and structure would both sections have. If they are completely different sections with different UI design, then of course it would be better to create 2 subdomains.

But if theme UI are the same, it would just have different content sections, then of course it would be better two create 2 pages.

Usually in similar cases  "creating 2 pages" are better. No need to switch from one wp-admin to another, no need to configure the theme 2 times, no need spend 2 times more time to routine management tasks.